# How to know if a Notification is a persistent one using NotificationListenerService

Tags: android, notifications, notification-listener

In my app I'm using the NotificationListenerService.

How can I know if a notification that was posted is a persistent notification that cannot be swiped away, like the "WhatsApp Web is currently Active" notification.

Is it the flag `FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT` in the variable `flags`? Or is it saved somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm gonna answer my own question.
Yes it is.

The flags `FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT` or `FLAG_NO_CLEAR` in the variable `flags` is how you know if a notification is persistent